# How to create a stylesheet that can accommodate all situations of styling (nested, sibling, etc.)?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a universal stylesheet for a massive website. I want to be able to create something that will stand as a base for everything, and if something specific is needed, then it can be included in another stylesheet as part of the cascade.

Ideally, if an `<h1>` is followed by an `<h3>`, then I want a specific margin, but if that `<h1>` is followed by a `<p>`, then I want the margin to be different.

**Is there a style or solution to creating something that can serve as a base for all my styles, which I can work off of if I need greater specificity down the line?**

However, the following...

```
h1 h3 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: blue;
}
```

...isn't the same as...

```
h1 + h3 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: green;
}
```

...neither of which will work on...

```
<header>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="sub-title">
    <div class="super-sub-title">
      <h3>The Real World</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

```css
h1 h3 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: blue;
}

h1 + * h3 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="sub-title">
    <div class="super-sub-title">
      <div class="super-duper-sub-title">
        <h3>The Real World</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: When you say "followed by" do you mean a descendant of, or a sibling of?

Comment: Followed by meaning sibling of. But I'm looking to account for nested selectors and classes as well.

Comment: What about `h1 + * > h3`?

Comment: That's great! Is there an option to account for greater nested HTML classes? i.e.; `  <div class="sub-title">
    <div class="super-sub-title">
      <h3>The Real World</h3>
    </div>
  </div>`?

I understand how to use the universal selector, but what about the deeper nested items?

Comment: Not sure I follow with the code in your last comment. Can you update your question?

Comment: Check the snippet... I think I figured it out... I just removed the `>` from the specificity and that will account for all elements no matter the parenting level.

Comment: Ok now I see what you meant. Yes, the `>` selects a matching child, and removing it will select any matching descendant (not just the child level)

Comment: Thanks for your help!